# Como verificar se a lista esta vazia ou com um elemento em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, hash, hashcode

```
typedef struct {
    int tamanho;
    nodo *inicio;
} lista;

typedef struct {
    lista **vet;
    int tamTabHash;
    int colisoes;
} tabHash; 

tabHash *criaTabelaHash(int tamanho){
    if(tamanho < 1) return NULL;
    tabHash* hash = (tabHash*)malloc(sizeof(tabHash));
    hash->tamTabHash = tamanho;
    hash->colisoes = 0;  
    hash->vet = (lista**)calloc(tamanho, sizeof(lista*));
    return hash;
}

void gerarRelatorioHash(tabHash *th) {
    int i;

    int listocupada = 0, listvazia = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < th->tamTabHash ; i++) {
        if(th->vet[i]->tamanho >= 0) { // essa linha me da falha de segmentacao
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa linha do `if` tem um `{` sem um `}`.

Comment: me esqueci de colocar na hora de enviar a pergunta mas no código esta certo.  Eu estou lendo um txt com 10 mil  nomes, quando eu mando gerar o relatório ele da 1918 Falha de segmentação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejamos esse código:

```
    hash->vet = (lista**)calloc(tamanho, sizeof(lista*));
```

O `hash->vet` vai apontar para uma área de memória que contém uma quantidade de ponteiros inicialmente nulos. Essa quantidade é dada por `tamanho`.

Supondo que esses ponteiros não sejam todos sobreescritos com alguma outra coisa, isso significa que ao acessar `if(th->vet[i]->tamanho >= 0)`, se o `th->vet[i]` produzir um ponteiro nulo, ao fazer o `->tamanho` o resultado será uma falha de segmentação.

Para saber qual é a melhor solução, seria necessário você informar mais coisas sobre o contexto no qual as funções `criaTabelaHash` e `gerarRelatorioHash` são utilizadas. No entanto, supondo que de fato seja possível que `th->vet[i]` possa ser nulo, uma possível solução seria alterar o `if` para ficar assim:

```
        if (th->vet[i] && th->vet[i]->tamanho >= 0) {
```

Comment: funcionou obrigado

Comment: @FelipeSantos Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 